# What is the prerequisite for apksigner.bat or apksigner.jar

Tags: android, apk, signature, apksigner

In the build-tools folder there is an apksigner.bat and a lib folder which contains apksigner.jar

When I run any command by windows cmd, they both return nothing!

```
apksigner verify --print-certs 1.apk
```

Which one should I use to verify signature?
What is the prerequisite? JDK7, JRE8? I'm on win 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i used apksigner.jar and the command below:

```
java -jar apksigner.jar verify --print-certs 1.apk
```